# How do I transform a matrix into a vector?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this matrix that contains x number of products and feedback rankings of 5 different categories.
This matrix is represented in a Pandas DataFrame like this:

| index | Bad ratings | Slightly bad ratings | Neutral ratings | Slightly good ratings | Good ratings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| product1 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| product2 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| product3 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| product4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| product5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 4 |

How do I transform a matrix such as this to show the overall rank of each product?
E.g. like this where 0 is the worst and 9 is the best:

| index | Overall ratings |
| --- | --- |
| product1 | 1 |
| product2 | 3 |
| product3 | 2 |
| product4 | 3 |
| product5 | 4 |

Comment: And how is the "Overall Rating" calculated? Do you have a function, that takes the number for all 5 categories as argument?

Comment: You need to define an algorithm to combine the ratings into an overall 'score'; for example is 1 bad rating worse than 2 slightly bad etc.

Comment: @maow I guess this is part of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df['Bad ratings'] *= -2
df['Slightly bad ratings'] *= -1
df['Good ratings'] *= 2

df.set_index('index').sum(1).rank().sort_values()
```

Output:

```
index
product1     1.0
product3     2.0
product4     3.0
product2     4.0
product5     5.0
```